# Why won't my train go to the depot for regular maintenance?

Tags: openttd

In all games I play it seems like my trains are not doing scheduled maintenance at all even though they are scheduled to do so every 150 days. This only happens to my trains i.e. it works fine for planes, road vehicles and ships.

I usually have path signals on my tracks - <s>but it does not seem to differ if I have a path signal in front of the depot or not.</s>

Am I missing something specific to trains regarding the maintenance? Can they use any depot or are they bound to specific ones?

**Update:** I made a minimal reproduction of my issue and it seems that the train stops doing maintenance when I put the path signal as on the image below (removing the signal and the train immediately goes to the depot). But I am not sure why that signal prevents the maintenance?

[image: Depot with one path signal]

Comment: They should be able to use any depot at all.  What might be happening is when the maintenance triggers, they are directed to the nearest depot as the bird flies, instead of the nearest one on their track.

Comment: @fbueckert The problem seem to not be the distance to the depot but my use of signals, see the screenshot.

Comment: Is the signal a "regular" path signal or 1-way? A 1-way path signal  in the spot shown in your screenshot would prevent the train from going to the depot.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals It's a "regular" path signal. The 1-way signal has a small horizontal bar below the lights.

Comment: According to the wiki (http://wiki.openttd.org/Signals#Path_Signals), the "Two-Way" path signal triggers a penalty in the pathfinder algorithm for trains passing through it on it's back side. I'd venture a guess that when a train is trying to find a maintenance depot, there may be a bug (or feature) where the pathfinder rules out that depot due to the pathfinding penalty. However, this is pure speculation (and thus it's a comment and not an answer :))

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. Maybe it is a pathing quirk. I suggest that you try, just for fun, the put path signals on the other 2 sides of the Y intersection to see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

Shamelessly copying from [Jon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/337/jon-quarfoth):

> According to [the wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Signals#Path_Signals), the "Two-Way" path signal triggers a penalty in the pathfinder algorithm for trains passing through it on it's back side. I'd venture a guess that when a train is trying to find a maintenance depot, there may be a bug (or feature) where the pathfinder rules out that depot due to the path-finding penalty.

Comment: Yes, and I can reproduce this problem using other penalties. I put 5 road crossings between a depot and the main track, and the train refused maintenance. When I removed 2 road crossings, the train went for service.